# bytearray:set_size(5) fails for Lua Wireshark

Tags: lua, wireshark

In a Lua-based dissector, I would like to transform a tvb content to an other tvb. The code:

```
local strbuf = buffer(offset, strlen * 2) -- range from tvb
offset = offset + strlen * 2

local inbytes = strbuf:bytes()
local outbytes = ByteArray.new()            
outbytes:set_size(strlen) -- fails; using a number instead strlen fails to
```

The fail message is `expected userdata, got number`. Why would set_size expect userdata? Alternatively, how do I allocate a ByteArray of a given size?

Comment: Whithout knowing exactly what ByteArray.set_size expects, it's difficult to give you an answer. It would help if you provided a link explaining what a "Lua-based dissector" is, or which one you were using.

Comment: @kikito This is the API doc for wireshark lua: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/lua_module_Tvb.html

Comment: @ron, I couldn't reproduce this in Wireshark 1.7.0 on OSX (the code above has no problem). Which Wireshark version and OS are you running?

Comment: @superuser: It is 1.6.2 32bit (Lua 5.1) on a 64bit Win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you found a bug in their implementation. According to their own API, creating an empty ByteArray isn't incompatible with using set_size.

I could not find an issue tracker for it, but you could try sending the bug you found to their mailing list: https://www.wireshark.org/mailman/listinfo/wireshark-dev

As an workaround, have you tried initializing the ByteArray with just an empty string?

```
local outbytes = ByteArray.new("") -- notice the empty string here            
outbytes:set_size(strlen)
```

Comment: Yes, using any init string (even larger than the set_size parameter) still yields to a set_size error later. lhf's solution can be used however to create an initial string buffer just with the right size

Comment: Wireshark bugs should be submitted to [http://bugs.wireshark.org](http://bugs.wireshark.org).

Answer (score 0):

The following works, but is not too elegant:

```
local s = ""
for i = 0, strlen-1 do
    s = s .. "ff"
end
local outbytes = ByteArray.new(s)
```

Comment: The loop can be replaced by `s=string.rep("ff",strlen)`.